# Insert data in Fusion Tables using RefreshToken

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, token, google-fusion-tables

I'm unable to find this information, I can get data from a Google Fusion Table, but I can't Update the table without having passed access token. Google documentation is quite a mess and it's complicated to find this information, the Python code samples are outdated.

```
requests.post(url_api, params={'access_token': <access_token>, 
sql': "INSERT INTO " +  table_id + " (address) VALUES ('Test text')",
'key': fusion_api})
```

And I got a 401 error, I'm getting access token from the Google OAuth API using refresh token.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}
```

I checked my token through Google API  :

```
{
 "issued_to": "XXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "audience": "XXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables",
 "expires_in": 3600,
 "access_type": "offline"
}
```

Does the access type has something to do with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to fix that issue by removing the fusion_api key in the parameters :

```
headers = {'Authorization': bearer_str ,'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Host': 'www.googleapis.com'}
params = {
    'sql':"SELECT * FROM " + table_id,
    'key': fusion_api
}
```

to

```
headers = {'Authorization': bearer_str ,'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Host': 'www.googleapis.com'}
params = {
    'sql':"SELECT * FROM " + table_id
}
```